# web.py template module suddenly missing

Tags: python, wsgi, web.py

I started with some web.py samples on a VHS.  Very basic stuff and generally working after some tinkering.  This includes custom forms and sessions in web.py

I then decided to tackle the challenge of combining a few things but at the same time decided to do it locally.  I basically combined forms and sessions to create a little math game.

It is working so I wanted to move it back to the VHS, but I got this error:

```
# python math.py 84
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "math.py", line 3, in <module>
    import web
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    import utils, db, net, wsgi, http, webapi, httpserver, debugerror
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    import http
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web/http.py", line 16, in <module>
    import net, utils, webapi as web
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web/webapi.py", line 31, in <module>
    import sys, cgi, Cookie, pprint, urlparse, urllib
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/cgi.py", line 49, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/random.py", line 45, in <module>
    from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
  File "/data/home/hartz/nginx/rest/math/math.py", line 6, in <module>
    render = web.template.render('templates/')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'template'
```

The exact same example is however working on my local PC.  I then tried to run my previous forms template examples and they now all produce the same error, so there is something wrong with the environment, and the fact that it started just as I uploaded the "working game" to the VHS is just a co-incidence?  I'm guessing this is related to the python environment or virtualenv, which I don't think I'm using, since I found it confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

Rename the program to something more obscure - math.py evidently clashes with python's standard modules.  But that isn't enough - you also need to delete the "math.pyc" file since that will still be seen by python and used by python for any python program executed when in that directory!

I don't know why I don't have the same problem on my local PC - it may be related to differences in the virtualenv and/or the python version (v2.6.9 on the VHS, versus v2.7.6 on my PC)